# Sentence segmentation/tokenization with Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to tokenize/segment sentences from a large text. [The University of Illinois](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/tools_view/2) offers a nice Perl script that splits texts into sentences, but I don't know about its accuracy and I think I should give it a try.

I have downloaded the script and the command-line usage appears to work, but it is not producing the expected results. The input and output files remain the same, although its documentation says that the program checks sentence boundaries and the program output is a text file where each text line corresponds to one sentence.

I am a PHP developer and not well versed with Perl scripts, so can anybody with Perl programming knowledge figure out where the problem lies?

This is the command line I am using (I have renamed the script to `boundary.pl`)

```
perl.exe boundary.pl -d HONORIFICS -i input.txt -o output.txt
```

Comment: without seeing the relevant code, a sample input, the expected output and the actual output it's not particularly possible to give any sort of answer. Could you have a read of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  and update your question with a **minimal** example which exhibits the unexpected behaviour

Comment: As it stands, the script has the shebang line `#!/local/all/perl`. Have you fixed that, or are you running on Windows?

Comment: I too tried using the UoI code. It seems to work fine on linux. Are you using it on Windows? Is there any compatability issues?

Comment: Yes, I am on Windows. Do I need to change the shebang line?

Answer (score 1):

There is a perl module to do this from the widely used CPAN library http://search.cpan.org/~kimryan/Lingua-EN-Sentence-0.29/lib/Lingua/EN/Sentence.pm . You can install it with then 'cpan' command line utility that comes with Perl.

You would need to add a small amount of code to create the output of split sentences, but the synopsis shows you most of what you need.